# Woocommerce + php question - generating cupon code at order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to generate an unique cupon code for each client when placing an order and attaching this code at the end of the order confirmation email. This is what I came up with:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'generate_coupon_on_order_complete', 10, 1 );
function generate_coupon_on_order_complete( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

    $coupon_code = $order->get_meta( 'generated_coupon_code' );
    if ( $coupon_code ) {
        return;
    }

    $coupon_code = substr( md5( uniqid( wp_rand(), true ) ), 0, 5 );
    // setați valoarea de reducere la 10%
    $discount_amount = 10;

    $expiry_date = strtotime( '+30 days' );

    $coupon = array(
        'post_title' => $coupon_code,
        'post_content' => '',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_author' => 1,
        'post_type' => 'shop_coupon'
    );
    $new_coupon_id = wp_insert_post( $coupon );

    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'discount_type', 'percent' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'coupon_amount', $discount_amount );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'individual_use', 'yes' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'product_ids', '' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'exclude_product_ids', '' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'usage_limit', '1' );
    update_post_meta( $new_coupon_id, 'expiry_date', $expiry_date );

    $order->update_meta_data( 'generated_coupon_code', $coupon_code );
    $order->save();
}


add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_details', 'add_coupon_code_to_order_email', 10, 4 );
function add_coupon_code_to_order_email( $order_email, $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text ) {
    // verificați dacă clientul a primit deja un cupon generat în această comandă
    $coupon_code = $order->get_meta( 'generated_coupon_code' );
    if ( $coupon_code ) {
        $coupon_message = "<p>Pentru a-ți mulțumi pentru comandă, am generat un cupon de reducere pentru următoarea ta comandă.</p>
                            <p>Cuponul tău de reducere este: <strong>$coupon_code</strong>.</p>
                            <p>Pentru a folosi acest cupon, adaugă produsele dorite în coșul de cumpărături și introdu codul la finalizare.</p>";
        $order_email .= $coupon_message;
    }
    return $order_email;
}
```

Problem is that I get an error on this line:

```
$coupon_code = $order->get_meta( 'generated_coupon_code' );
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? thank you

Upon placing a new order, the coupon code is generated, the order is generated in the background, but the checkout window freezes and no confirmation email is sent.

Comment: What error are you getting on this line: $coupon_code = $order->get_meta( 'generated_coupon_code' );. Have you checked the error log?

Comment: Looks like you got the parameters for your callback function wrong? According to https://wp-kama.com/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_email_order_details, the `woocommerce_email_order_details` callback function should take `$order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email`, in that order. Yours is taking `$order_email, $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text`.

Comment: Oh Im stupid, youre right, the order was wrong. Thanks!